# Does Matlab offer robust standard errors for GLMs?

Tags: matlab, glm, poisson, standard-error

I'm trying to do Poisson regression with overdispersed data and so I believe I should be using huber-white robust standard errors.

However, I don't see any option for that in glmfit. And from what I understand, robustfit is only for linear regression. Am I correct in this? Is there a way to do Poisson regression with robust standard errors in Matlab?